# TDD Django - Shopping Cart

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, django, e-commerce

I'm new in Python TDD and I would like to ask you about some feedback for Django unit testing.

```
import datetime
from decimal import Decimal
from django.test import TestCase, RequestFactory
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from cart.models import Cart, CartItem
from cart.mixins import get_cart
from cart.context_processors import cart_count_processor
from products.models.product import Product
from profiles.models import Profile
from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser
from django.contrib.messages import get_messages


class CartViewsTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.request = RequestFactory()
        self.request.session = {}
        self.request.anonymous_user = AnonymousUser()

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        cls.test_product = Product(
            name='Testing Product',
            slug='testing-product',
            created_at=datetime.datetime.now(),
            updated_at=datetime.datetime.now(),
            price=1000,
            perex='Lorem ipsum',
            content='Lorem ipsum content',
        )

        cls.test_product.save()

    def _create_testing_cart(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cart = Cart(created=datetime.datetime.now(), updated=datetime.datetime.now(), *args, **kwargs)
        cart.save()

        return cart

    def _create_testing_cart_item(self, cart_instance, product_instance):
        cart_item = CartItem(cart=cart_instance, product=product_instance, quantity=1,
                             date_added=datetime.datetime.now())
        cart_item.save()

        return cart_item

    @staticmethod
    def _create_testing_user():
        user = Profile(
            email='vomacka@gmail.com',
            name='Martin',
            surname='Vomacka',
            slug='martin-vomacka',
            is_active=True,
            is_admin=False,
            is_staff=False,
        )
        user.set_password(raw_password='helloworld')
        user.save()

        return user

    def test_cart_string_representation(self):
        cart = self._create_testing_cart()
        self.assertEqual(str(cart), 'Cart id: {id}'.format(id=cart.pk))

    def test_empty_cart_view(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse('cart:index'))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    def test_resolve_cart_for_logged_in_user(self):
        session = self.client.session
        session['user_cart'] = 'testing_session'

        request = self.client.get(reverse('cart:index'))
        request.user = self._create_testing_user()
        request.session = session

        testing_cart = self._create_testing_cart()
        testing_cart.session_key = request.session['user_cart']
        testing_cart.user = request.user
        testing_cart.save()

        cart = get_cart(request)

        self.assertEqual(request.status_code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(cart, testing_cart)

    def test_resolve_cart_for_anonymous_user(self):
        session = self.client.session

        testing_cart = self._create_testing_cart()
        testing_cart.session_key = session.session_key
        testing_cart.save()

        request = self.client.get(reverse('cart:index'))
        request.session = session
        request.user = AnonymousUser()

        self.assertEqual(request.status_code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(request.context['cart'], testing_cart)

    def test_string_representation_cart_item(self):
        cart = self._create_testing_cart()
        cart_item = self._create_testing_cart_item(cart_instance=cart, product_instance=self.test_product)

        self.assertEqual(str(cart_item), cart_item.product.name)

    def test_cart_item_url(self):
        cart = self._create_testing_cart()
        cart_item = self._create_testing_cart_item(cart_instance=cart, product_instance=self.test_product)
        response = self.client.get(cart_item.get_absolute_url())
        self.assertTrue(response.status_code, 200)

    def test_deleting_cart_item(self):
        session = self.client.session

        cart = self._create_testing_cart()
        cart.session_key = session.session_key
        cart.save()

        cart_item = self._create_testing_cart_item(cart_instance=cart, product_instance=self.test_product)

        response = self.client.post(reverse('cart:remove', kwargs={'product_id': cart_item.product_id}),
                                    data={'product_id': cart_item.product_id}, follow=True)

        messages = [msg for msg in get_messages(response.wsgi_request)]

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(messages[0].tags, 'success', 'Message type should return success type')
        self.assertEqual(messages[0].message, 'The item has been deleted from your cart.',
                         'Message text should be equal to: The item has been deleted from your cart')
        self.assertEqual(cart.cartitem_set.count(), 0, 'Cart should have zero items.')

    def test_updating_cart_item(self):
        session = self.client.session

        cart = self._create_testing_cart()
        cart.session_key = session.session_key
        cart.save()

        cart_item = self._create_testing_cart_item(cart_instance=cart, product_instance=self.test_product)

        response = self.client.post(reverse('cart:update', kwargs={'product_id': cart_item.product_id}),
                                    data={'cart_item_quantity': '2'}, follow=True)

        messages = [msg for msg in get_messages(response.wsgi_request)]

        updated_quantity = response.context['cart'].cartitem_set.first().quantity
        cart_item.quantity = updated_quantity
        cart_item.save()

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(cart_item.quantity, 2)
        self.assertEqual(cart_item.total_price, Decimal(cart_item.quantity * cart_item.product.price))
        self.assertEqual(messages[0].tags, 'success', 'Message type should return success type')
        self.assertEqual(messages[0].message, 'Product quantity has been updated.')

    def test_amending_quantity_on_existing_item(self):
        session = self.client.session

        request = self.client.post(reverse('cart:add', kwargs={'product_id': self.test_product.id}),
                                   data={'quantity': 1}, follow=True)
        request.session = session
        request.user = AnonymousUser()

        quantity = 1

        cart = get_cart(request)
        cart_item, cart_item_created = CartItem.objects.update_or_create(cart=cart, product=self.test_product)

        if cart_item_created == False:
            cart_item.quantity += quantity

        cart_item.save()

        self.assertEqual(cart_item.quantity, 2)

    def test_adding_item_to_cart_as_anonymous_user(self):
        response = self.client.post(reverse('cart:add', kwargs={'product_id': self.test_product.id}),
                                    data={'quantity': 2}, follow=True)

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(response.context['cart'].cartitem_set.first().quantity, 2,
                         'Quantity should be equal to 2')
        self.assertEqual(response.context['cart'].cartitem_set.count(), 1)

    def test_adding_item_to_cart_as_logged_user(self):
        session = self.client.session
        session['user_cart'] = 'cart_session'

        test_user = self._create_testing_user()

        response = self.client.post(reverse('cart:add', kwargs={'product_id': self.test_product.id}),
                                    data={'quantity': 3}, follow=True)

        response.session = session
        response.user = test_user

        cart, created = Cart.objects.get_or_create(session_key=response.session['user_cart'], user=response.user)
        cart.save()

        self.assertRedirects(response, '/cart/', 302)
        self.assertEqual(response.context['cart'].cartitem_set.count(), 1)
        self.assertEqual(response.context['cart'].cartitem_set.first().quantity, 3)

    def test_get_total_quantity_of_items_in_cart(self):
        session = self.client.session
        session['user_cart'] = 'cart_session'

        cart = self._create_testing_cart()

        # Products
        product = self.test_product
        product_2 = self.test_product

        cart_item = self._create_testing_cart_item(cart_instance=cart, product_instance=product)
        cart_item.quantity = 3
        cart_item.save()

        cart_item_2 = self._create_testing_cart_item(cart_instance=cart, product_instance=product_2)
        cart_item_2.quantity = 2
        cart_item_2.save()

        cart.save()

        total_qty_of_items = cart.get_total_quantity_of_items()

        self.assertEqual(total_qty_of_items, 5, "It should return 5")

    def test_context_processors(self):
        session = self.client.session

        cart = self._create_testing_cart()
        cart_item = self._create_testing_cart_item(cart_instance=cart, product_instance=self.test_product)
        cart_item.quantity = 3
        cart_item.save()

        cart.session_key = session.session_key
        cart.save()

        request = self.client.get(reverse('cart:index'))
        request.session = session
        request.user = self.request.anonymous_user

        total_qty = cart_count_processor(request)

        self.assertEqual(total_qty['cart_items_count'], 3, "Total quantity should be equal to 3")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is, of course, important to see the code under test to get the idea of the quality and coverage of your test, but here are some generic things that I've spotted after glancing over the tests, from top to bottom:

- [organize imports as per PEP8 recommendations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports): first system-level imports, then third-parties, then your local project dependencies, alphabetically
- I think your tests may benefit from using *Model Factories* (like [`factory_boy`](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)) to simplify generating model instances on the fly, avoid repetitive procedures and improve on readability and resusability
- the test itself is a bit lengthy, consider splitting into smaller tests, grouping test cases logically
- I think you meant to use `assertEqual()` instead of `assertTrue()` here:

  ```
  self.assertTrue(response.status_code, 200)  # assertEqual?
  ```
- there is probably no need to define a separate `quantity` variable just to use it right after the definition. I think it will be perfectly okay to just use the value `1` for the quantity considering that there is a single product being created
- `if cart_item_created == False:` can be simplified to `if not cart_item_created:`
- when you call `get_or_create()` and unpack the result into two variables, you don't use the second one. In Python, there is a [recommendation for this kind of throw-away variables - use `_` as a variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python):

  ```
  cart, _ = Cart.objects.get_or_create(session_key=response.session['user_cart'], user=response.user)
  ```
- there is probably not a lot of meaning in the `# Products` comment
- and overall, consider adding meaningful comments or/and docstrings to your test methods